# text box (input type number)spinner not working in IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am using input tag to display and change the number of decimals in my application.Instead of allowing the users to type in the text box,I want it to decrement or increment with help of spinner.For that I'm using type as number.

```
 <input type='number' step="1" onkeydown="return false" min="0" max="3" id='txtDecimalsCount' value="0">
```

This works fine in Chrome and firefox.But it seems that IE11 does not support this feature.
I found a pollyfill here 
https://github.com/jonstipe/number-polyfill

But this is a huge js which contains additional features and I have no idea how to use it.

Is there any other simple way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

IE11 does not, natively, support steps and spinners so you need a workaround, unfortunately. Whether by writing a custom implementation or by using a polyfill.

To write your own implementation in javascript, you would have to add event listeners which check the value of input[type="number"] elements (or, in case you only need to check it for a couple, perhaps add a special class and select them via that) after every keyup event on each input and compare it to step defined in the input html element and then check whether the value of that input is within its' max and min ranges defined (if they are defined). That's the simplest way.